# Attic Wiring Using 12-3 and 12-2 pulling from ceiling outlet

Tags: lighting, attic

I am adding attic lights, and will be pulling power from the garage's constant power ceiling outlet. The switch will be close the the attic ladder opening. There will be 3 lights daisy chained in the attic. With the middle light in the series being closest to the power source, I am planning on using 12-3 to send power to the switch via the middle light.

Question: The outlet box has 12-2 and now I am not sure how to draw the power from the box to the switch (without having to go from the ceiling outlet box all the way to the switch, just to go all the way back down the daisy chained lights.) Am I missing something to make this work? Or is there only one option?

Answer (score 2):

Your question leaves me a bit unclear about the relationship of the various parts:

- I'd assume that a ceiling outlet (floor of the attic) would be closer to the hatch/switch than the light above is. In which case Run 12/2 from the outlet to the switch, and 12/2 from the switch to the lights.
- If it appears to actually make sense for reasons I can't see without a diagram, run power on 12/2 from the outlet to the middle light, then run 12/3 from the middle light to the switch location. Connect the middle light to red/white. Connect black from the outlet to black(and white to white, and grounds all connected is assumed to be obvious.) If that path passes **through** one of the other lights, connect the light to red/white. Connect the switch to red/black. If the path to the switch does not pass through a light, run 12/2 from the closest light to it, and connect the black of that cable to the red (and white to white, and grounds all connected is assumed to be obvious.)
- given the usual relative prices of 12/2 and 12/3, it might cost less to use more wire to make a longer run from the outlet to the switch, and not have to buy any 12/3, wiring it as in the first point.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Black Wire for the hot (phase), white for neutral, These are on the existing plug. Run the 3 conductor wire between all of the lights. Connect the lights from white neutral to red power. Connect a switch somewhere convenient from the black to red. Be sure you connect all the safety grounds. You can use a 12X2 to power the system. Depending on your breaker you may be able to use #14 wire if it is a 15A breaker, if not stay with the #12.